# Deploy create-react-app build version to Heroku

Tags: javascript, reactjs, heroku, production-environment, create-react-app

I'm working with a create-react-app generated app which I'm deploying to Heroku. I would like to test out the production version `npm run build` in an actual server.

Is it possible to serve the build version instead of the development version to heroku? It's okay if I can no longer have the dev version up in that heroku instance.

If possible, *how can I do so*, I have been searching up and nothing comes up

Answer (score 1):

If you're following [standard documentation](https://blog.heroku.com/deploying-react-with-zero-configuration) on how to deploy react app to heroku, you're already running the production build on heroku.

That documentation uses [`create-react-app-buildback`](https://github.com/mars/create-react-app-buildpack) for deployment and serving the app via Nginx. You can refer to [this section](https://github.com/mars/create-react-app-buildpack#user-content-web-server) that explains that the app is served from build directory

There is a way to verify this too. If you have [react developer tools](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi?hl=en) extension installed on your browser, it shows if the app is running production version or development version.